# MassPay in PayPal

Tags: grails, paypal

Just to see im not in a mistake.

I need to use MassPay feature in my project, so an user can take the balance he has in my site, and transfer it to his paypal account. In the documentation available in the paypal site, there is an [example class](https://www.x.com/paypal-apis-masspay-java-1.6/soap). I understand that, in my code, i must call the massPayCode method (with proper parameters). The problem is, that class hasn't got a constructor, so, how can i call that method? and of course... am I focusing the problem in the proper way?

Thank you!

(BTW, im using Grails)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is, that class hasn't got a constructor...

In java, if no constructor is defined, a default no argument constructor will be provided.  So if you decide just to copy that java class to your application, you can call `new MassPay()` to get a new instance.